# java swing form hang

Tags: java, swing

I am developing an application in java Swing(desktop) that communicate to device through Serial port.the problem is that it hangs when communication lost with device.and I am unable to close the Form until I don't end the .exe in window task mannager.what should be solution so that i can close the forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are communicating with the other application by using the Event Dispatch Thread. If the other application hangs then your GUI becomes unresponsive.

I would suggest you use a separate Thread to communicate with the other device.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.